Mathematica's Nothing for Python lists, tuples and dictionaries
Mathematica has an object called Nothing that when put into a list automatically disappears.
For example, {a, b, Nothing, c, d, Nothing} automatically evaluates to {a, b, c, d}.
Does something analogous exist for python?
I tried x = (1, 2, 3, 4 if True, 5) which complains about the lack of an else statement.  Moving to x = (1, 2, 3, 4 if True else None, 5) succeeds but y = (1, 2, 3, 4 if False else None, 5) gives (1, 2, 3, None, 5) whereas what I want is (1, 2, 3, 5), so None is kept while Nothing would be dropped.
If there is such a thing, does it work for [lists,] and {'dict': 'ionaries'}?

you could filter() out the None items during or after creation of the list using filter() or a comprehension.

Indeed.  In a list comprehension you don't need the else and it gives the filter.  But I want a hand-built list.  I don't mind doing the filter because the tuple I've got is small, but it seems ugly.

Why do you want to have element which would disappear anyway?

The application seems to be very specific to Mathematica. What would be the use case in Python?

Would this work for you tuple(i for i in range(1, 6) if i != 4 or False)?

@JonSG Why or False?

@evanb if it's ugly, make a function out of it, so the ugliness reduces to y = clean((1, 2, 3, None, 5))

@deceze to mimic what the OP had to exclude 4 I understand it is extranious, I just wanted to show something as close as possible to what the OP had with their test.

@JonSG That'd work the same without or False.

I have a tuple of objects; I want one to be omitted in a certain case.  That tuple is then passed to various other algorithms.  It's much easier to say: o = ( ..., the object if W !=1, ...) than if W==1: o = (... without the object ...) else o= (... with the object ...)
In my real use the assignment to o spans multiple lines; it is much easier to avoid repeating myself by using something Nothing-like.  Another way would be o = (...) + ((the object,) if W != else ()) + (...) but that is not particularly pleasing looking, seems unpythonic.

@deceze yes, I realize that, but I wanted something to try to mimic the OP's 4 if False else None code. Presumably they want a more elaborate test than just excluding 4

@Daweo I don't want an element that disappears.  What I really want is the first case, (1, 2, 3, 4 if False, 5) to evaluate to (1, 2, 3, 5) but that raises an error.  The point is to conditionally appear in the tuple.

@AlexeyS.Larionov this is a one-off use, seems excessive.

@JonSG in the actual use case the different items are not so straightforward to enumerate as range(1, 6) but that's the right idea.  It seems very strange to me that you can filter inside a list comprehension but not in a manual list construction.

A list/tuple literal results exactly in whatever you type. [a, b, c] is a list with exactly three elements, only what the exact values are is up for debate. If you need to generate a list more dynamically than this, then you employ some construct like a loop, comprehension, filter, map, or anything else that fits the need. Looking at the documentation you linked, Nothing seems to have pretty specific use cases in mind (the example shows removing items from a plot easily), which is not all that relevant to Python, thus an equivalent doesn't exist.

@deceze : see my answer for a Python construct which is equivalent to Mathematica Nothing.

@deceze the linked example is just one use case; there many many uses, it just takes getting used to as a way to think.  Its use is not any different conceptually than the if statement in a list comprehension, but it can be used for a manually constructed tuple.

I would like to point out that the reason for closing this question is not valid because the question asks for an equivalent for Mathematica's Nothing and not how to embed a condition without using else which is clearly and fully another kind of question.

I understand that the idea of replacing something with Nothing, so that this something vanishes to exist is a bit alien to Python coders and causes wondering what it could be good for. With another set of mind, different from the one influenced by coding Python the concept of Nothing can appear very useful and important to have and worth giving it another thought or even a PEP ...

(4,) if True else () evaluates to either the tuple (4,) or empty tuple (), so unpacking it you can write x = (1,2,3,*((4,) if True else ()),5).
Almost exactly the same thing works for lists, x = [1,2,3,*((4,) if True else ()),5].
Unpacking a dictionary also works: x = {'a':1, **({'b':2} if True else {})}.

I would just use None and then a filter.
x = (1, 2, 3, None, 5)
x = tuple(filter(None, x))

If you want a one-liner:
x = tuple(x for x in (1, 2, 3, None, 5) if x is not None)
# or
x = tuple(filter(None, (1, 2, 3, None, 5)))

If you want a function that constructs a tuple, you can use:
def tup(*items):
    return tuple(filter(None, items))

x = tup(1,2,3,None,5)


Note: if None is the only falsey value you expect in the sequence, filter(None, ...) will do just fine without the bulky lambda.

If I were to go to industrial-strength I'd probably create a sentinel to make sure only actually-Nothing gets filtered out, but this is a good demonstration.

@evanb.  Yeah, but creating a singleton class is probably overkill for this question.
